# Instantiating COM class giving an error

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I executed the following C# code to Test environment and PROD server:

This code checks if it is able to instantiate COM classes on the servers:

```
     try
            {
                Type creatorType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("A.B");

                MessageBox.Show("Trying to create instance for :" + "A.B");

                creator = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(creatorType);

                MessageBox.Show("A.B object instance is : " + creator.GetType().ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

This code is working fine on my machine, Test environment but not in PROD.
On PROD, am getting an error message: "Value cannot be null.Parameter name:type" at the line :-->

```
creator = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(creatorType);
```

The required COM dlls are installed on PROD server.What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: You might wanna provide the error that you are receiving as well? What is the COM error?

Comment: I've mentioned the error message in my question: "
Value cannot be null.Parameter name:type

Comment: Seems like the real question is Why Does `Type.GetTypeFromProgID("A.B")` return null? The usual answer is that the component isn't there. Or is there but not registered, that sort of thing.

Comment: Is "creatorType " retrieved correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, on that line, i guess only creatorType can be null. And because creatorType is returned by Type.GetTypeFromProgID, that method might returns (as MSDN says):

The type associated with the specified ProgID, if progID is a valid entry in the registry and a type is associated with it; otherwise, null.

So, it might mean that your COM dlls are not installed OK on your server. Can you find your COM dlls in the registry?

Comment: Thanks Andrei Pana....yes,the problem was that ProgId was missing from the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes .And hence, creatorType was returning null.